# In bash, when sending a curl request, is there a way to break a very long url onto the next line?

Tags: bash, curl

For example, using two of the backslashes don't seem to help:

```
curl "https://www.somewebsitethatjustkeepsgoing.com/jflawfelaifjliajsefaslaslfajslie&alksdjf \\
    ?andsomemore=2235233 \\
    --output my.pdf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A double backslash simply means "put a literal backslash here". If you want to extend a url across multiple lines, just use a single backslash...and no whitespace.  For example:

```
curl goo\
gle.com
```